# Define Functions for OnClick in React Component with ES6 Syntax

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I currently structure my React Components the following:

```
export default class Heading extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <h1 onClick={changeLanguage("en_US")}>I am a Heading!</h1>
      );
    }
}
```

And now after some research I haven't found any way to define functions inside the Component Class that can be used inside the onClick attribute of something.
Everything I found was only for React.createClass or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to define the method inside of your component. You will need to wrap your event handler so you can pass an argument to it

```
export default class Heading extends Component {

   changeLanguage(lang){
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <h1 onClick={()=>this.changeLanguage("en_US")}>I am a Heading!</h1>
   )}
```

Comment: I was stupid and put "function" before the function, which VSCode told me doesn't work. But with the `()=>` I don't even need a function anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the function is outside the render, you would refer to it like so:

```
export default class Heading extends Component {
    changeLanguage = () => {
         //do something
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <h1 onClick={()=>this.changeLanguage("en_US")}>I am a Heading!</h1>
      );
    }
}
```

changeLangue needs to be an arrow function to maintain context.